# Adding a FooterView to custom CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I’ve implemented a custom FlowLayout subclass, which does not allow to just check the box for Section Footer via the storyboard (the check box is gone).

Is there any other way to do so using storyboards or does that mean I am forced to do it programmatically?

What I am looking for the app to do is have the footer raise as the user scrolls the collection view down. If the collection view is empty then the footer view should be displayed by default.

A great example of what I am trying to achieve is the RetailMeNow iPhone app?

Comment: Implement `func layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?` in your custom layout.

Comment: Can you elaborate please?!